# Unit test in multi-module spring boot project

Tags: spring-boot, junit4, spring-boot-test, multi-module

I have multi-module project with similar structure as below:

- server (which includes Application Context Configuration) and other configurations
- shared (Utility classes used by other modules)
- service (module with various repository and services)
- transaction (module which handles transaction)
  I need to write test for the project but I cannot change the project structure. I created a test in my transaction module.

First I got

> Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test

I solved it by Creating a @Configuration file in the test folder like so

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.mohen")
public class TestConfig {
}
```

And then I used it in the `@SpringBootTest(TestConfig.class)` .I was able to autowire, the IDE did not show any sign of error. But when I run my tests I get NoSuchBeanDefinitionException from a different class that is trying to autowire a dependency from the service module.

How to solve these issues?

The main configuration file of the application looks like

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.mohen")
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
@Import(value = {SSIpFilter.class, MainConfig.class})
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {...}
```

The MainConfig.class contains componentScan and Import annotation.

If I try to Import the MainConfig.class in my test I get a suggestion to add a dependency to the server module, which I would not want to do.

Also the entire application uses a single property file (yml). Where should I keep my property file for the test?

**EDIT**

I managed to run the tests, a dataJpaTest and an integration test, but it loads the entire application context.

Now the problem is, the tests that pass normally , fail when I build my project `./gradlew clean build`

I get

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

in some classes and

> Caused by: javassist.NotFoundException

in other.

I have tried adding the javaassist library but it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Comment: your explanation of your project structure and all annotations is all over the place, it is impossible for us to get a clear picture of your structure. This is probably why you have these errors, because the structure ir messy. Unless you can actually show us the actual structure and all annotations, or produce a minimal working example, then you are probably out of luck.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61058907/gradle-fails-to-build-at-test There you go sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my question. Due to the project being multi module, the classes and the packages were not being recognized by other modules. 
I made a few changes in my build.gradle files of the modules.

```
testRuntime project(':shared')
```

I added the above in the dependencies and also added

```
jar {
    enabled = true
}
bootRepackage{
    enabled = false
}
```

The jar creates a simple non executable jar file while the bootRepackage disables the creation of an executable jar which by default is its nature.